# function call after the deployement of the app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I wanna know if there is a function that is called directly after the deployment of the server. This functions could be called as an initialisation function of the deployment. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may still be a way to do it without this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a single app, you can implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), listening on the `contextInitialized()` event. You can register an implementation through the `<listener>` tag in your web.xml.

Comment: This will happen every time a new instance of your app is started, not just once per deployment.

Comment: @NickJohnson I didn't think of that. Depending on what he wants to accomplish it's probably still fine though, since I can't see the use case for this on a per-global-deployment basis.